# 2 Way databinding for Webview and ProgressBar

Tags: android, data-binding, webview, 2-way-object-databinding

I am trying to implement 2 way databinding for WebView and Progressbar.

Initially ProgressBar will continue to appear and as soon as webview finishes loading , progress bar should be GONE.

But I am not able to create that binding

I have created Binding adapter for webview to load url and also set WebViewClient to check page loading is finished but cannot update the visibility of progressbar

////////////// Post

```
@BindingAdapter({"app:webUrl"})
    public void configureWebView(WebView iWebView, String iUrl) {

        iWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        iWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                // code to set visibility of progress bar
            }
        });

        iWebView.loadUrl(iUrl);
    }
```

//////////////////// Layout

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="newsUrl"
            type="com.example.bindingdemo.data.model.Post" />
    </data>


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/news_web_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:webUrl="@{newsUrl.url}" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/news_prog_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="@{**<WhatConditionToWrite>** ? View.GONE: View.Visible}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `BindingAdapter`

```
@BindingAdapter({ "setWebViewClient" })
public static void setWebViewClient(WebView view, WebViewClient client) {
    view.setWebViewClient(client);
}

@BindingAdapter({ "loadUrl" })
public static void loadUrl(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
}
```

In your `ViewModel`

```
public class YourObjectModel extends BaseObservable {

    private class Client extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request,
            WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            setHideProgress(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            setHideProgress(true);
        }
    }

    public WebViewClient getWebViewClient() {
        return new Client();
    }

    @Bindable
    public boolean isHideProgress() {
        return hideProgress;
    }

    private void setHideProgress(boolean hideProgress) {
        this.hideProgress = hideProgress;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.hideProgress);
    }
}
```

`XML`

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="YourObjectModel"
            />
    </data>
    <WebView 
            ... 
            app:loadUrl="@{viewModel.url}"  
            app:setWebViewClient="@{viewModel.webViewClient}" />
    <ProgressBar 
            ... 
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.hideProgress ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}" />

</layout>
```

Comment: I am not using any ViewModel. Just the Model class holding data and simple data binding. Can we do that ?

Comment: @Napolean this Model is the ViewModel ^^

Comment: Thanks Phan. It worked. I just changed 
hideProgress to be as following with accessors and mutators
public ObservableBoolean hideProgress = new ObservableBoolean();

Comment: We can merge the multipe binding adapters

    @BindingAdapter({"loadUrl", "setWebViewClient"})
    public static void loadUrl(WebView view, String url, WebViewClient client) {
 view.setWebViewClient(client)
        view.loadUrl(url);
    }